# SQL api, Concat an url for images returns '\/' instead of '/'. How do you encode it?

Tags: sql, api, url, geoserver

I want to get img as URL (eg):

https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg

What im trying:

```
https://geofa.geodanmark.dk/api/v2/sql/fkg?q=
SELECT fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.geometri, fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.facil_ty, fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat, concat('https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/',fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat,'.jpg') as img
FROM fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt INNER JOIN fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse 
ON fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.objekt_id = fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_objek WHERE facil_ty='Legeplads' &format=geojson&geoformat=geojson&srs=25832
```

Works, but returns img as:

```
https:\/\/mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/fkg\/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg
```

[image]

With encoding:

```
https://geofa.geodanmark.dk/api/v2/sql/fkg?q=
SELECT fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.geometri, fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.facil_ty, fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat, concat('https:%2F%2Fmapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Ffkg%2F',fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat,'.jpg') as img
FROM fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt INNER JOIN fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse 
ON fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.objekt_id = fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_objek WHERE facil_ty='Legeplads' &format=geojson&geoformat=geojson&srs=25832
```

Still:

```
https:\/\/mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/fkg\/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg
```

[image]

I DONT want this:

```
    https:\/\/mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/fkg\/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg
```

i WANT this:

https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg

BECAUSE i need the URL:

```
    style='background-image: url(<%= 'img' %>);
```

And i does not accept /.

Is it possible to find an solution?

Comment: What's the problem with the given result? The URL looks properly escaped to me

Comment: if i take the resulting URL i get: 
        https:\/\/mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/fkg\/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg

i need https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/311fd222-a8bd-487c-bccb-d756bac994a6.jpg

Comment: Whatever you mean by "take", why not unescape the given URL?

Comment: im using the url later in the code with html, where I need the URL for the image. Not sure how i can unescape i

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain more details about how you call that API (using PHP, using JS, using something completely different)

Comment: the call (just copy paste it to the browser) https://geofa.geodanmark.dk/api/v2/sql/fkg?q=
SELECT fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.geometri, fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.facil_ty, fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat, concat('https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/',fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat,'.jpg') as img
FROM fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt INNER JOIN fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse 
ON fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.objekt_id = fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_objek WHERE facil_ty='Legeplads' &format=geojson&geoformat=geojson&srs=25832 
returns a geojson. ind img get the url with '\/' instead of '/'.

Comment: https://geofa.geodanmark.dk/api/v2/sql/fkg?q=
SELECT fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.geometri, fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.facil_ty, fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat, concat('https://mapcentia-www.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fkg/',fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_lokat,'.jpg') as img
FROM fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt INNER JOIN fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse 
ON fkg.t_5800_fac_pkt.objekt_id = fkg.t_7900_fotoforbindelse.foto_objek WHERE facil_ty='Legeplads' &format=geojson&geoformat=geojson&srs=25832

Comment: Please add **all** clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: Happy now? Or what else do you need

Comment: You forgot to share which programming language you use. Also, did you even try to unescape the URL?